# How to store logs for a pm2 start command

Tags: reactjs, logging, next.js, yarnpkg, pm2

I have a appliation that runs using pm2.

I need to store logs in a separate space rather than default place

Currently we use the following for running the application:

```
pm2 start yarn --name "application-name" --interpreter bash -- serve
```

If I try the following to store the logs:

```
pm2 start yarn --name "applicationame" --interpreter bash -- serve -o "/path" -e "/path" -log-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"
```

The above command is failing the application. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: "The above command is failing the application" - Can you be more specific? How is it failing?

Comment: It is saying as unknown command -o do you have any other ideas for implementation for this?